# Contional for a Target Membership

Tags: swift, xcode, target

I have a file *(FileA)* in Xcode that most of my targets use. I need to call on a function from another file *(FileB)* that's only for one of my targets. I can not call on FileB's function from inside FileA because inside FileB's "Target Memberships" I only have the target selected that's needed for it. I can not add the other targets to FileB because it uses Cocoapods that my other targets (e.g., home screen widget target) do not have access to.

**Is there a conditional (some if-statement) that can be for targets?**

For example:

```
if (targetMembership == FileB) { doFuntion() }
```

This is a large file so duplicating it would not be smart. Does anyone know how to handle this?

**FileA Structure:**

```
final class CoreDataManager {
   static let sharedManager = CoreDataManager()
   lavy var persistentContainer: NSPersisentContainer = {
      setupContainer()
   }

   private func setupContainer() -> NSPersistentContainer {
   //call FileB method in here
   }
}
```

**FileB Structure:**

```
class FileB {
   static func someFunction(error: Error) {
   //code I need
   }
}
```

Comment: Create FileC with the function you need instead of having it in FileB and add FileC to all the required targets?

Comment: Unfortunately can't. FileB is just one function that uses a certain CocoaPod method that other targets do not have :(

Comment: OK. One other thought....  Give the code in FileA a delegate to call instead of calling into FileB directly.  The implementation of the delegate can be different depending on which target is using FileA.  One of them may call `doFunction()` and the others may do nothing.

Comment: That's interesting! My only experience with delegates is between ViewControllers. FileA is a final class and I need to call FileB's function in its init method. FileB is another class too with just the static function. How would I use the delegate? I updated my question to show the structure!

Comment: "FileB is just one function that uses a certain CocoaPod method that other targets do not have" I think `#if canImport(TheModuleName)` can help you here.

Comment: @Alexander that silenced the errors!! Thank you!